# Java row websocket data transfer

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, serversocket

So basically i have java ServerSocket connected with browser which has js websocket on it. After correct handshaking i'm reciving data in this cycle

```
while((d = in.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(d));
}
```

Client sends data with

```
socket.send(send_data.value);
```

Where send_data is an input element;
And when i send data repeatedly i always get different bytes, and what is most important - **number of bytes is not divisible by 4**.
Why is this happening? Should i use some ByteBuffer stuff or flush()?

Comment: d type is integer

Comment: What is `send_data.value` ? Which libraries are you using? What gets logged?

Comment: 1) send_data is JS variable which stores link to input element object. So send_data.value is some string.
2) Pure Js an Java SE 11
3) https://github.com/alexbutav/websocket/tree/dev Files :  echoServer.java and client.html 

P.S. Seems like i've misunderstood framing protocol and num of bytes must not always be divisible by 4.